# Parser combinators prevent mapping of strings

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, ambiguous, parser-combinators, implicits

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

object SimpleArith extends JavaTokenParsers {
    "abc".map(identity)
```

produces

> type mismatch;  found   : String("abc")  required: ?{def map: ?} Note
>   that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are
>   ambiguous:  both method augmentString in object Predef of type (x:
>   String)scala.collection.immutable.StringOps  and method literal in
>   trait RegexParsers of type (s: String)SimpleArith.Parser[String]  are
>   possible conversion functions from String("abc") to ?{def map: ?}

How do you workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways I can think of. First, you could call the sepcific desired implicit function (it can always be used explicitly):

```
augmentString("abc").map(identity)
```

Second, force casting to the required type (this requires you to import `scala.collection.immutable.StringOps`, or specify fully-qualified class name):

```
("abc": StringOps).map(identity)
```

Third, you can move the `.map` or other string-manipulation code into a method somewhere else where the parser implicits are out of scope, and call that method. Eg:

```
trait StringMappings {
  def mapStr(str: String) = str.map(identity)
}
```

and

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

object SimpleArith extends JavaTokenParsers with StringMappings {
  mapStr("abc")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient but any noob like me can come about with toList of char

```
str.toList.map ...
```